# "candidates for cross-border leadership assignments" in Chinese?

Tags: translation

I've had some trouble translating this phrase into Chinese:"candidates for cross-border leadership assignments".
Can anyone help me please?

Will be glad for your help :)

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Can I have the full paragraph? If not here's the translation
跨境領導任務的人選

Comment: Well the full sentence looks like this: "They search and select candidates for cross-border leadership assignments and unique requirements". So I think the translation you offered fits here quite well. Thank you!